# Macro to Transfer Specific Table Content in MS Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have around 50 word documents in an old format which I need to convert to a new format. I was thinking of having a new format template and copying needed numbered fields from the old format into the new format using a macro, and finally saving this new document.

I have numbered fields from 1 to 6 in the old format where some fields are in the header. I need these fields in the new format where the sequence is different.

I am a absolute beginner in macros and need to submit this tomorrow so would appreciate any help or advise urgently.

Word documents download links are mentioned below:

OLD FORMAT : http://www.scribd.com/R0cKyMan/d/90470134-Old-Format

NEW FORMAT : http://www.scribd.com/R0cKyMan/d/90473107-New-Format

Comment: `need to submit this tomorrow` : Yes this can be done using macros but honestly, I doubt if you will get a complete solution written for you here in SO. If you `don't have time` and are not keen on experimenting with macros then I would suggest visiting sites like odesk.com or freelancer.com There someone can write the entire application for you in couple of hours. And if you are interested in learning how it is done, then I can help you here :)

Comment: ya that will be great if you could teach me how do we go about this as i can show my vba code progress tomorrow and may be submit it in the next 2-3 days.The tough part is how do we use the new format as we need template for the new format and then start copying respective fields there and finally saving the newly created document.Also what would be the destination for pasting the copied fields.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett I have recorded a macro for author name field:  `Sub CopyAutName()
      ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2).Select

      ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Select

      Selection.Copy

          

      Windows("New Format.doc [Compatibility Mode]").Activate

      ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Select

      Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)

End Sub`

Comment: Okay, and did this work? What was your next step? If you want us to help, you are going to have to make it *easy* for us to help. Pasting a bunch of code in a comment, for instance, is not useful. Edit your question. Make it clearer. Demonstrate effort.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett The above code copies the author which is in the body from old to new. Im facing issues in copying header from old doc to new as some fields are in the header for the new and a field in the body for the new. So can u help me out with copy header fields. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > So can u help me out with copy header fields. Thanks – R0cKy 3 mins ago

---

The tables in the `Header` have to be accessed in a different way.

When a table is in the body, you can use it like this

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

But to access the table which is in the `Header` you have to access the `Section` in which the Header is. In your case the table is in `wdHeaderFooterPrimary`

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Copies the 2nd Cell in the first row of a table which is in the Header
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Select
    Selection.Copy

    '~~> Pastes it in say 1st cell in Row 1 of a table which is in the body
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Select
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Tried the above code with the destination as New Format.doc as i need to paste in the new document so used this code line before paste in your code `Windows("New Format.doc [Compatibility Mode]").Activate`, but getting error saying requested member of the collection doesnot exist runtime error 5941

Comment: You have to put that before this line `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Select`

Comment: yup i did that but still getting this error.also i need to paste in the header so modified ur line with this `ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Select` Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Two things 1) Remove `.Doc` from your code 2) I believe you have posted the code in `ThisDocument` code area. Insert a module and paste it there. Now try it

Comment: Thanks...done as u said and now it is working fine :)